# View-based NSOutlineView ignoring subview positioning?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm experiencing an odd problem with the view-based NSOutlineView I'm using as a source list. Despite items in the template view being arranged as desired, both elements return to their default positions when the application is run. This is a problem, because it means that the placement is nonstandard compared to Apple and other third-party Mac applications, plus it just looks bad.

Here's a comparison:

[image: Comparison]

Has anybody else had this problem? If so, how did you get around it?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you referring to the left-to-right spacing of "personal", the icon, and the label, compared with the image on the left?

Comment: Ahh, I should have clarified. I'm talking about the placement of the actual items (icon and label) - header placement is fine as it is. On a side note, since posting this I tried changing the indentation value of the outline view in interface builder and it doesn't have an effect either.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand what you want to see instead.

Comment: Take the screenshot on the right (with Personal, Bookmarks, etc) and compare it to the source list in the Finder or iTunes. I'm trying to get the indentation and position to match those, but the outline view discards any changes I make to element positioning.

Comment: So, the rows should be taller, the icons' centers should be lined up vertically, there should be more space between the icons and the left edge, and there should be slightly more space between the icons and the labels? Does the outline view completely ignore your template?

Comment: Under lion, your row height depends on a setting in System Preferences > General, but yes, that's the general idea. The template is ignored entirely unless I remove the default elements and add my own, but if I add my own the source list no longer scales with the system setting properly.

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm having all sorts of ridiculous indentation issues. It's maddening. I'm surprised Apple hasn't made the source list easier to implement considering it's a staple of modern OS X applications. Same goes for the Preferences window, but that's a rant for another day. Anyway, if you have any helpful advice, or if you figured out a nice workaround when dealing with your issues, would you mind letting me know? Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get back to you sooner! For a while, I resorted to manually moving the view’s controls around before display through delegate methods, which turned out to be wildly inefficient. For a bit after that, I adjusted the width of the view before displaying, which worked better but still wasn’t ideal. At some point, the problem fixed itself… now, source lists in my applications compiled against the 10.8 and 10.9 SDKs lack these positioning problems. I haven’t tested but I suspect the problem shows up when targeting 10.6 or 10.7.